# How to make a slash command respond with an embed to a certain person

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const ms = require('ms');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { ApplicationCommandType, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'profile',
    description: 'View the profile of a certain user',
    voiceChannel: false,
    options: [
    {
        name: 'user',
        description: 'Select a user',
        type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
        required: true,
    }
    ],

async execute({ inter }) {

const error = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor('#ff0000')
.setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true }) })
.setTitle('❌ Error')
.setDescription('There was an error whilst executing this command!')
.setFooter({ text: 'Powered by Nonay', iconURL: inter.member.avatarURL({ dynamic: true })});

const MYPROFILE1 = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor('#5679EF')
.setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true }) })
.setTitle('⚙ My Profile')
.addFields(
    { name: 'lots of things here', value: 'things i guess' },
)
.setFooter({ text: 'Powered by Nonay', iconURL: inter.member.avatarURL({ dynamic: true })});

const MYPROFILE2 = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor('#5679EF')
.setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true }) })
.setTitle('⚙ My Profile')
.addFields(
    { name: 'Profile', value: 'it worked' },
)
.setFooter({ text: 'Powered by Nonay', iconURL: inter.member.avatarURL({ dynamic: true })});

    const user1 = inter.options.getUser('user');
    if (user1 == "Coke#0666") return inter.reply({ embeds: [error], ephemeral: true })
    await inter.reply({ embeds: [MYPROFILE1] })

    if (user1 == "Clorophyte#9014") return inter.reply({ embeds: [MYPROFILE1], ephemeral: true })

},
};
```

Above is my block of code and I have been trying to make it so that if a certain user selects my profile it will respond with a certain embed. I have tried many times but to no avail.

Oh and if someone doesn't enter in a username that hasn't been specified, how do I make an else if statement in this situation?

Now I did try some people's suggestions but it just sends the error embed instead of the correct embed I want it to reply with

Answer (score 0):

For the bot to respond to a certain user only, use [`ephemeral`](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#ephemeral-responses):

```js
if (user1 !== "Coke#0666") return inter.reply({ embeds: [error], ephemeral: true })
await inter.reply({ embeds: [MYPROFILE1], ephemeral: true })
```

Edit:

```js
if (user1.tag === "Coke#0666") return inter.reply({ embeds: [embed1] })
else if (user1.tag === "KNguyen#8442") return inter.reply({ embeds: [embed2] })
// else if ...
else return inter.reply({ embeds: [embedn] })
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help but just wondering how this would work if it was looking for multiple users at once :)

Comment: Hi I checked out your code and it doesn't appear to work but thanks for the help anyways

Comment: @Coke does your bot message show like [this](https://i.imgur.com/ACLFKkv.png)?

Comment: it is showing as ephemeral but it isnt what im searching for, it pastes the error embed for every user i select and doesnt show the specified embed

Comment: @Coke can you show me the screenshot of your issue?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Pt1aBFZ - It keeps sending the same embed even when I choose another user and yes, I have changed the embed in the code but it doesn't do what I want it to do. It just sends the error embed constantly and I don't think the code you sent me, works with multiple users as it is meant to send different embeds for different users

Comment: @Coke ohh so you want to make /profile command? if yes then i can edit my answer

Comment: Not quite, I need it to send a certain embed when a certain user is mentioned as the question states. Example: If User 'Coke' is mentioned = send certain embed and If User Edfour10 is mentioned = send another embed

Comment: user1.tag is not defined

Comment: oops sorry, i forgot how v14 user input work

Comment: @Coke maybe .user will work?

Comment: user isnt defined

Comment: @Coke idk but for me, user1.tag works for me even v14.2.0